# Поиск суммы в скользящем окне от локального максимума в другом столбце до конца окна

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Имеется колонка 'A' с числовыми значениями. Размер тысяча строк.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(100, size=1000)})
```

С помощью метода `Series.rolling()` ищем максимум в скользящем окне из 50 значений колонки 'A' и записываем этот максимум в новую колонку 'B':

```
df['B'] = df['A'].rolling(50).max()
```

Требуется найти сумму числовых значений по колонке 'X' от строки, в которой находится максимум колонки 'A' для данного скользящего окна, до конца окна.

Например, для скользящего окна по колонке 'A' с 21 по 70 строки найден максимум на 42 строчке. Надо найти сумму чисел от 42 строчки до 70 для колонки 'X' и записать его на 70 строчке в новой колонке 'C'. И так обработать все строчки до конца таблицы.

Comment: а чем 'B' от 'X' отличаются?

Comment: Значениями отличаются. Представим, что исходная таблица содержит много столбцов помимо столбца 'A'. В том числе там есть и столбец 'X'.

Comment: а окно как ведёт себя? первая строка + 49 следующих, 49 предыдущих? что с остатком в конце или в начале соответственно?

Comment: Есть таблица из 1000 строк. В ней 2 столбца 'A','X'.

Comment: Есть таблица из 1000 строк. В ней 2 столбца 'A','X'. Для первого расчета берем строки с 1 по 50. Находим в колонке 'A' максимум, записываем в столбец 'B' на 50 строчке. От строки, на которой максимум (например, 21) считаем сумму по колонке 'X' от 21 до 50 строчки, записываем ее в колонку 'C' на 50 строчке.  Далее делаем сдвиг на 1 строчку и начинаем рассматривать данные с 1 по 51 строчку. Находим по ним максимум в колонке 'A' (например, также на 21 строке), записываем в колонку 'B' на 51 строчке. Считаем сумму по 'X' с 21 по 51 строки и записываем в колонку 'C' на 51 строчке. И так до конца.

Comment: там получится что у 49 не будет `c` а еще у 49 не будет  `b`, см. мой пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame (для сравнения я взял те же значения для столбцов `X` и `A`, что и в ответе от @Eugene Dennis):

```
In [458]: df
Out[458]:
     X    A
ID
1   67  230
2   63  757
3   35  170
4   47  369
5   18  547
6   72  590
7   34  499
8   69  785
9   44  973
10  27  373
```

векторизированное решение:

```
window = 3

def f(win, df, val_col='X'):
    return df[val_col].loc[win.idxmax() : win.index.max()].sum()

df['B'] = df['A'].rolling(window).max()
df['C'] = (df['A'].rolling(window)
                  .apply(lambda win: f(win, df, 'X').sum(), raw=False))
```

результат:

```
In [465]: df
Out[465]:
     X    A      B      C
ID
1   67  230    NaN    NaN
2   63  757    NaN    NaN
3   35  170  757.0   98.0
4   47  369  757.0  145.0
5   18  547  547.0   18.0
6   72  590  590.0   72.0
7   34  499  590.0  106.0
8   69  785  785.0   69.0
9   44  973  973.0   44.0
10  27  373  973.0   71.0
```

Comment: Это круто. Код в несколько раз меньше, чем второе решение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Реализация без pd, таблица 10 строк, окно 3 (конец окна на строке):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random


# класс для генерации уникальных идентификаторов
class RowUID:
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0

    # метод получения нового следующего уникального id
    def new_id(self):
        self.n += 1
        return self.n


# класс таблицы с методами на все строки или на одну
class Table:
    # инициализируем таблицу как словарь, где ключ уникальный id, значение - экземпляр класса Row
    def __init__(self):
        self.row_dict = {}

    # забор строки по id
    def select_row(self, id_):
        return self.row_dict[id_]

    # замена значения в словаре таблицы на новый экхемпляр класса Row
    def edit_row(self, id_, row):
        self.row_dict[id_] = row

    # Проверка наличия в таблице указанного id 1-есть 0-нет
    def show_id(self, number_id):
        try:
            m = self.row_dict[number_id]
            return 1
        except KeyError:
            return 0

    # Функция для расчёта максимального значения в поле а, на вход список id
    def max_value_a(self, ids):
        max_a, max_i = 0, 0
        for i in ids:
            row_ = self.select_row(i)
            if row_.a > max_a:
                max_a, max_i = row_.a, i
        return max_a, max_i

    # Сумма по полю х - на вход список id - что складывать
    def sum_value_x(self, ids):
        return sum([self.select_row(i_).x for i_ in ids])

    # Расчёт поля b с окном для одной строки, на вход id и размер окна
    def calc_window_b(self, id_, window_size):
        # узнаём первый id
        first_id = id_ - window_size + 1
        # если он существует можем рассчитать b
        if bool(self.show_id(first_id)):
            # определяем участников
            b_list_id = range(first_id, id_ + 1)
            # закидываем id участников в функцию для поиска максимального - узнаем значение и id
            mx_b, mx_id = self.max_value_a(b_list_id)
            # извлекаем строку
            m = self.select_row(id_)
            # назначаем b и id
            m.b = mx_b
            m.b_id = mx_id
            # записываем изменения
            self.edit_row(id_, m)

    # Расчёт поля с окном для одной строки, на вход id и размер окна
    def calc_window_c(self, id_, window_size):
        # если есть вверх элементы на количество размера окна
        first_id = id_ - window_size + 1
        if bool(self.show_id(first_id)):
            # если от максимального b вниз существует количество элементов по размеру окна > 1
            m = self.select_row(id_)
            b_id = m.b_id
            if b_id >= first_id:
                # формируем список участников
                c_list_id = range(b_id, first_id + window_size)
                # Вызываем функцию расчёта суммы
                sum_c = self.sum_value_x(c_list_id)
                # выбираем строку
                n = self.select_row(c_list_id[-1])
                # присваеваем значение в строке
                n.c = sum_c
                n.c_id = '+'.join([str(g) for g in c_list_id])
                # записываем изменения в таблицу
                self.edit_row(c_list_id[-1], n)

    # печать в консоль таблицы
    def print_rows(self):
        # функция для форматирования "ровные столбцы" ширина по умолчанию 10
        def sp(x, y=6):
            if bool(x):
                return x + (y - len(x))*" "
        # печатаем заголовки
        print sp("id"), "|", sp("x"), "|", sp("a"), "|", sp("b"), "|", sp("b_id"), "|", sp("c"), "|", sp("c_id")
        # печатаем строки
        for p in self.row_dict:
            u = self.row_dict[p]
            print sp(str(u.id)), "|", sp(str(u.x)), "|", sp(str(u.a)), "|", sp(str(u.b)), "|", sp(str(u.b_id)), "|", \
                sp(str(u.c)), "|", sp(u.c_id, 20)


# класс строки с атрибутами
class Row:
    def __init__(self, id_, input_a, input_b):
        self.id = id_.new_id()
        self.a = input_a
        self.x = input_b
        self.b = None
        self.b_id = None
        self.c = None
        self.c_id = None

# создаём экземпляр класса уникальных id
id_generator = RowUID()
print id_generator.new_id()
# создаём экземпляр таблицы
tab = Table()
# генерируем столбец а и x
a_col = [random.randint(100, 999) for x in range(1, 11)]
x_col = [random.randint(11, 99) for y in range(1, 11)]
# закидывем строки в таблицу
for la, lx in zip(a_col, x_col):
    row = Row(id_generator, la, lx)
    tab.edit_row(row.id, row)
# рассчитываем b
for k in tab.row_dict.keys():
    tab.calc_window_b(k, 3)
# рассчитываем с
for p in tab.row_dict.keys():
    tab.calc_window_c(p, 3)
# печать
tab.print_rows()

    id     | x      | a      | b      | b_id   | c      | c_id
    2      | 67     | 626    | None   | None   | None   | None
    3      | 19     | 735    | None   | None   | None   | None
    4      | 57     | 284    | 735    | 3      | 76     | 3+4
    5      | 83     | 312    | 735    | 3      | 159    | 3+4+5
    6      | 42     | 729    | 729    | 6      | 42     | 6
    7      | 34     | 682    | 729    | 6      | 76     | 6+7
    8      | 56     | 578    | 729    | 6      | 132    | 6+7+8
    9      | 15     | 480    | 682    | 7      | 105    | 7+8+9
    10     | 24     | 725    | 725    | 10     | 24     | 10
    11     | 18     | 125    | 725    | 10     | 42     | 10+11
```

Comment: Идея в целом похоже на то, что хотелось бы иметь. Но реализация некорректна. В колонке 'b' находится максимум из последующих N=3 строк (а нужно из предыдущих). Но при этом в колонке 'c' считается сумма по колонке 'x' от максимума из колонки 'b' в скользящем окне N=3. При этом это скользящее окно - вверх от текущей строчки (как и надо). Только там неправильные максимумы от нижних строчек. И надо считать от первого максимума в окне, а не от ближайшего. Пример: строка 3 с=98 (63+35), а первый максимум в окне из 3 строк - на 1 строчке: 67+63+35=165.

Comment: могу под-шаманить, в таком виде вам подойдёт (классами)? я добавлю входные выходные

Comment: Спасибо большое. Пойдет классами. Только добавьте немного комментариев в код, чтобы проще было понять, где и что считается. Я только начал изучать Питон. В таблице нужно еще и другие расчеты делать, попробую в этом коде сам добавлять нужный функционал.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Попробую разобраться с кодом, чтобы потом самостоятельно добавлять функционал по обработке данных в таблице.